# Get location data for a program using GPS dongle

Tags: gps

I'm working on vehicle tracking system using GPS. What I want to do is connect GPS receiver to my laptop and fetch the location data in to my program. I have seen many commercial GPS receivers and dongles. Those devices providing there own driver software. Is there any way to fetch those location data in to my program using those devices.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most GPS receivers output data in a serial format called "NMEA-0183" - it is readable ASCII text, normally sent at 4800 baud.

If the receiver has a USB port, it will normally appear as a normal serial port, so you should not need any special drivers.

If the receiver has an NMEA-0183 or RS-232 output, you will probably need an RS-232 to USB converter.  Again, the computer should already have the necessary drivers.

Offically, NMEA-0183 should use differential signalling, and 0 - 5 volts, but most RS-232 serial ports should be able to receive the data correctly, using only one of the NMEA-0183 wires.

Your program will just have to read the data from a serial port.